# Align Top of Background with Bottom of Element with CSS

Tags: css, positioning

I want to align the top of a background image with the bottom of an element using CSS (so that I can make it `transition` in upon hover or in an animation, in case you were wondering). This element does not have a set height; I don't know what the height of the element is. Does anybody know how to do this? The solution does not have to be IE compatible; it only has to work in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

EDIT: I'll award the bounty to an answer that also works for the `<body>` element if there is such an answer by the time that the bounty ends.

Comment: Well, what didn't work was `background-position:center bottom`. That just puts the bottom edge of the background image against the bottom edge of the element. In my HTML, I have an empty `<div>` that's ready to receive this animation.

Comment: Can you use jquery/javascript as well ? Or do you want to do this only via CSS ?

Comment: I'm trying to keep this CSS-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take J Cole's second answer a bit further - if you want to avoid inserting an extra element you could always use pseudo-elements. For example:

```
.myElm {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.myElm:after{
    content:"";
    background: url("myimage.png") no-repeat top left;
    top:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.myElm:hover:after {
    top:0;  
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but yes, it should work for any element I believe.

Comment: Oh, wait, it wouldn't. Setting the `body` element to `overflow:hidden` would prevent the page from scrolling. That's a special case, though.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry about the trouble.  Gotta love CSS right?  Anyhow I have two solutions for you:  One just stays within the realms of using background positioning and achieves it... for the MOST part;  The other one goes outside of the immediate solution, adds just a little bit extra, but is rock solid and works with any height at all.  Both work with any width.

So the first one:

This works by setting the `background-position` to the keyword value `center` for the xpos and the percentage value `1000%` for the ypos.  Of course the % value can vary, but I just went with 1000% to be safe.  In reality you could make this just big enough to push it off screen.  But here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/D5QME/

The problem with this one is that if you make the height of the parent element the exact height of the background image... it quits working.  And if the height of the parent element shrinks below the height of the image, it reverse the pattern.  So if you're confident that the parent element will always be taller than the BG image, this is pretty solid.

---

Now the second one:

This one is straight up rock solid but adds an extra element.  This extra element can either be a placeholder element, like a `div` or whatever, or just the straight `img` itself.  This:

1)  Uses `position: relative` and `overflow: hidden` on the parent to turn it into a container

2)  Uses `position: relative`, `margin: 0 auto`, and `top: 100%` to position the image in the center and push it just below the parent

3)  and uses `.parent:hover .backgroundImage` to make the image transition to `top: 0%` when the user `hover`s over the parent element.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fwf6p/

Even though this adds an extra element, it is pretty rock solid.

---

Anyhow, hope this helps!

-J Cole Morrison

Comment: The first method doesn't line the top of the image with the bottom of the element. However, the second method works, I guess. I'll try it and see how it goes on my site.

Answer (score 2):

Another modification of [J Cole's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875803/1389880), but seems to work with the body tag.  May also work with [Hephistocles modification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11907065/1389880) but haven't tested that.

CSS:

```
.example{
    border: 1px solid red;
/* Change the height to anything you want! */       
    height: 400px;
/* Change the width to anything you want! */
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.example:hover .backgroundImage{
    height: inherit;
    top: 0%;
}

.backgroundImage{
    background: url("http://img.gadgetian.com/Angry-Birds-Space-021-300x300.png") no-repeat top center;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: 1s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 1s ease all;
    transition: 1s ease all;
    height: 0px;    
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="example">
    <div class="backgroundImage"></div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VGgmG/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I specifically said that we don't know what the height of the element is.

Comment: Height is handled exactly the same way as J Cole's answer.  I don't see where a height is specified, the 400px is for demo purposes only and not necessary.

Comment: In the case of the `body`, it gets its height from the contents of the document.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding, what is your expected behavior if the size of the body (parent element) is smaller than the size of the image, is that possible?

Comment: If the height of the element is less than the the height of the background image, the top of the image should be lined up with the bottom of the element at first. When the element is hovered over, the bottom of the image should be lined up with the bottom of the element.

Comment: Ok that much makes sense.  But your element has to have some height initially in order to be hovered over.  How do you expect that height to be defined?  Just curious now.

Comment: It's defined by the contents of the element. It gets taller as more stuff is put inside it.

Comment: Yes, but it has to have something inside it to start with.  In your question you stated it was an empty div, I believe it's impossible to hover over an empty div with no height.

Comment: No, I never said anything about `<div>`s in my question.

Comment: Even if the element was empty, it could still be set to `height:100%`, which is not an exact height.

Comment: 100% of nothing is still nothing? I believe this fiddle shows that http://jsfiddle.net/QC7js/11/  And you said you had an empty div in your comment of your question, "In my HTML, I have an empty <div> that's ready to receive this animation."

Comment: When you specify that the height of an element is `100%`, that means 100% of the parent element.
A comment on my question is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of your element in pixels, you may be able to set its background position to be: `background-position:0 npx;`.  Not sure otherwise.  If there's a maximum height, you could always just use that.  Or have a reasonable estimate/limit.  The transitions may not 'ease' very uniformly, however.

---

There was an excellent [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GSUv2/) in another answer just now, but it's been deleted :(

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong wording in my question, but I don't know the height of my element.

Comment: @wecsam: But there's a maximum, right? Your background image itself will have a finite height. Yes?

Comment: The background image itself has a definitive height. I can get that from the image editing program.

Comment: @wecsam: great, is your background image always enough to fit the element?  Can it ever be too small?

Comment: Well, I have it simply aligned to the bottom of the element right now, but you can sometimes see the top of the background image if you stretch the browser window enough.

Comment: @wecsam: Oh well, then perhaps you need to constrain your design further, perhaps using max-height.  If you're too fluid, then there are some things you just can't do perfectly.

Comment: I guess that the only solution is to use JavaScript, then.

Comment: @wecsam: You can set `style.backgroundPositionY` in JavaScript, and have the rest in CSS.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. To have it animate in, I just set `style.backgroundPositionY` to `""` or `null`.